# Jelly Bean loading assets

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've been testing my android app on the 2.3 OS, and until recently when I tested it on 4.1 all worked perfectly. My problem is that I load some XMLs from the asset folder and on the 2.3 all files are loading perfectly fine, but on 4.1 it doesn't load any file (no errors either). My question is if the loading is different from an OS to another.

This is my loading code:

```
    String xmlString = null;
    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    try 
    {
        InputStream is = am.open(path);
        int length = is.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        is.read(data);
        xmlString = new String(data);
    } 
    catch (IOException e1) 
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xmlString;
```

And for the xml loading I use DOM, and this is a part of it:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        String theXML = getXml();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(theXML.getBytes("utf-8"))));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeListHeadNode = doc.getElementsByTagName(headNode);


        for (int i = 0; i < nodeListHeadNode.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            //introduce the nodes into a list
        }
```

The project build target is Android 4.2.2

Comment: Did you look in the logcat to see if there are any relevant messages? Don't filter the logcat because you might miss something important/relevant. Also, if you are doing a large amount of file I/O on the main (UI) thread, Android will get pretty mad at you. You might think about doing this in a background thread.

Comment: You quite explictly say you use JDom to parse the XML, but your code is DOM code, not JDOM. I'm editing your tags to be DOM, not JDOM.